# How to access Service container instance from anywhere?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Ok, I have a background in ZF2 but Symfony 2 seems like works a bit weird for me...
My question regards on Services:

It is supposed to services are global. Why they are accessible only from controllers?
We suppose I have something like this:

```
src/Acme/AcmeBundle
   /Acme/SomeClass.php
```

How can I access Container service (i.e: $this->get/$this->container)from SomeClass.php?

Comment: well that is the main idea in Symfony. Inject only services you need, making your code highly testable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to do so (very rare situations), you shouldn't directly use container at all. Access to the container from within controllers is provided only for convenience but I would still consider it a bad practice.

In most cases you should register your custom class as a service with dependencies to specific services provided by the framework, 3rd-party bundles or by yourself:

```
// your service

namespace Acme;

class SomeClass {
    private $serviceA;
    private $serviceB;
    private $param;

    public function __construct(A $serviceA, B $serviceB, $param = 0) {
        $this->serviceA = $serviceA;
        $this->serviceB = $serviceB;
        $this->param = $param;
    }

    public function doSth() {
        // ...
    }
}

// service definition for container

<service id="my_service" class="Acme\SomeClass">
    <argument type="service" id="some_service_a" />
    <argument type="service" id="some_service_b" />
    <argument>123</argument>
</service>
```

Comment: OK, I noticed it in the docs but.. How can I access any services outside controllers?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"? Another, custom-made class? Just make it a container service and add dependencies as constructor arguments just like in the example above.

Comment: why is this accepted and upvoted? It doesn't answer the question at all, it just provides advice and another approach :(

Answer (score -1):

You have to use dependancy injection. Suppose you have a class src/Acme/AcmeBundle/SomeClass.php than it has setContainer function

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AcmeBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class SomeClass implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

/**
 *
 * @var ContainerInterface
 */
protected $container;

/**
 * Sets the Container associated with this Controller.
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface $container A ContainerInterface instance
 */
 public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
 {
  $this->container = $container;
 }

....
}
```

now you can define "SomeClass" as a service and inject service container like this.

```
<service id="some.service.id" class="Acme\AcmeBundle\SomeClass">
      <call method="setContainer">
         <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
      </call>
</service>
```

after this the "SomeClass"  would be accessible via service container by "some.service.id" and the service container would be injected into it.

Comment: OK, I nticed it in the docs but.. How can I access any services outside controllers?

Comment: You can access to your services through injections. You can inject service container or any particular service to any other service.

Answer (score -1):

Few weeks ago I wrote a post regarding how to inject services container.

Link :- http://anjanasilva.com/blog/injecting-services-in-symfony-2/

By the way, injecting services container used with care as this might not be the best approach.

Hope this helps
Regards

Comment: But, again: Only controller classes have access to container. That said I still could not to get 'database_conection' service - for exemple - from inside my user class src/Acme/MyClass.php;

Comment: Then inject the doctrine orm manager instead of services container.